# Passcode for pairing a bluetooth device

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm developing a Bluetooth app using Qt 5.5. Using `QBluetoothLocalDevice`, I can see the device which I want to pair for. Need to submit a passcode as part of the pairing process. How to do this?

Paired the same device with my phone and passcode entry showed up immediately.

```
connect(m_localDevice, &QBluetoothLocalDevice::error, this, &BluetoothModel::handleLocalDeviceError);
connect(m_localDevice, &QBluetoothLocalDevice::pairingDisplayConfirmation, this, &BluetoothModel::handlePairingDisplayConfirmation);
```

This isn't showing any debug message from `BluetoothModel::handlePairingDisplayConfirmation` slot. The debug / error messages are

```
qt.bluetooth.bluez: Failed to create pairing "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply"
BluetoothModel::setPairingStatusMessage "Pairing request failed."
```

Anyone tried doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm looking at using the QtBluetooth API for an app as well, but am having trouble understanding how to pass the PIN to use for the pairing request, as it's hardcoded in the device.

Comment: @dobey `Qt` bluetooth have no support for custom passkey as of now. You have to implement custom handler using `QDBus` module.